# How to detect if the referer is 404 page?

Tags: search

When entering search keywords on a search form on 404 page, the search results are displayed on a new page with the URL like this: `http://www.example.com/?s=xyz`.

How can I find if this search result is queried from a 404 page and not from a blog page or a product page?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and most robust way is to add a url parameter to the search so the search url will be something like http://www.example.com/?s=xyz&from404=1. Probably easiest way to do that is by adding a hidden field to the form.

For "bonus points" use the browser's history API to remove the parameter after the page load.